# Page method is returning content of whole page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, azure, azure-web-roles

My page method is returning whole page insted of result from the server side. In my local environment it is working fine but when I deploy it to azure I am getting this problem.

My code is:

```
function LoadLogsOnSucceeded(result) {
    document.getElementById('divHistoryHeader').innerHTML = result.Header;
    document.getElementById("divHistoryList").innerHTML = result.List;
}

function LoadLogs() {
    var searchTxt = $("#txtLogsearch").val();
    var maxRecords = $('select[id=drplogSearchMaxRecords]').val();

    PageMethods.LoadLogs(searchTxt, maxRecords, LoadLogsOnSucceeded, OnFailed);
}
```

In config I have not added

```
<httpModules>
  <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
</httpModules>
```

when I add that into my config then in local also project is not working getting error like

"The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred."

Comment: This is full js code what else do you need ?

Comment: In LoadLogsOnSucceeded(result) i am getting whole page content as a result instead of result from my server side code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solutions some configurations were missing in web.config
I added

```
<httpModules>
  <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
</httpModules>


  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.3.0.0" newVersion="2.2.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.0.0" newVersion="2.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

and now it is working fine